# при вставке данных в csv данные записываются в одну ячейку

Tags: javascript, reactjs, csv

Использую react-csv
Данные записываются в одну ячейку, почему?

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-csv

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { CSVLink } from 'react-csv';


const ExportReactCSV = (  ) => {
  const [state] = useState({
    headers : [
      { label: "First Name", key: "firstname" },
      { label: "Last Name", key: "lastname" },
      { label: "Email", key: "email" }
    ],

    data : [
      { firstname: "Ahmed", lastname: "Tomi", email: "ah@smthing.co.com" },
      { firstname: "Raed", lastname: "Labes", email: "rl@smthing.co.com" },
      { firstname: "Yezzi", lastname: "Min l3b", email: "ymin@cocococo.com" }
    ]
  })


  return (
    <CSVLink data={state.data} headers={state.headers} filename={"my-file.csv"} >Export</CSVLink>
  )
};

export default ExportReactCSV;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Похоже, что проблема в разделителе.

В CSV разделитель - запятая, но часто используются и другие разделители, например, точка с запятой ";".

Я думаю, что в react-csv стоит настройка "разделитель = запятая" (и ваша задача - найти, где эту настройку поменять), а в Excel стоит настройка "разделитель = точка с запятой".

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй это
`<CSVLink data={array} separator={";"}>Download me</CSVLink>`